# Assingning string variable contains URL with '&' symbols

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

while Assingning string variable contains URL with '&' symbols      vai query string
it splits string at '&' and the string after that is gone like below

query string contains strins like this `"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=34.0833869772674,74.7986488044262&zoom=21&size=550x450&maptype=roadmap&sensor=true"`

but when i assign this like below

```
string str = Request.QueryString["imgName"].ToString();
```

it contains `"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=34.0833869772674,74.7986488044262"` that part only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From MSDN:

`The QueryString collection retrieves the values of the variables in the HTTP query string. The HTTP query string is specified by the values following the question mark (?).`

In your case the QueryString collection would contain five members:
`center`, `zoom`, `size`, `maptype`, `sensor`.
Retrieve them like so:

`Request.QueryString("center")`

Similarly for the other variables as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Server.UrlEncode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx) method to produce save string for use in url. For example :

```
string queryString = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=34.0833869772674,74.7986488044262&zoom=21&size=550x450&maptype=roadmap&sensor=true";
Response.Redirect("http://www.mysite.com/?imgName=" 
                    + Server.UrlEncode(queryString));
```